# Can this 4'' PVC perforated sewer pipe be used for a french drain?

Tags: drain, pipe

I would like to use PVC pipe instead of corrugated pipe.
I went to HomeDepot (Canada) to see what is available and the below is my only choice. I don't think this will work as is since the lateral holes marked with blue are too high and the bottom ones are very few (2 in total for 120in!!)

By my opinion if the water does not reach around 1in depth at the bottom of the french drain this will never work since the bottom side has just 2 holes.

I am thinking about buying this and putting more holes there. Is that a good idea ?

[image]

Legend:
-blue dots -lateral holes
-red dots -bottom side holes

Comment: You could drill more holes if you like, but the holes that are in the pipe will work just as it is supposed to, to insure the drain stays open. The gravel is the workhorse here I believe. Sediment will eventually start to fill the French drain over time. The pipe insures it will move water over a long period of time in comparison to not using the pipe.

Comment: As you already know from my other question this will be installed between a patio and a wall. Since I am interested in just capturing the water that comes off the patio or off the underlying bedding do you think that it is a good idea to put plastic foil on the bottom of the trench and on the side of the trench that is in fact the wall of my home? 
I don't want any drop of the collected water to read the wall anymore. That wall is already wet and I want it to dry up as soon as possible after I install this french drain

Comment: I am modifying your latest sketch to explain a bit more of what you could do.